# elastic search ports mismatch + timed out error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I was following this link:

```
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-rails/0.1.7
```

to use "elastic-search" in my application but I have stuck due to silly error of ports mismatch. I get this:

```
Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200
```

Anyone seen this before? I am running server on my default port(3000 i.e. by using rails s).

Out of curiosity, I tried running server with port number as "9200" and this error replaced another error of TIMED_OUT. Error seen is:

```
Faraday::TimeoutError in Articles#search
```

EDITED : I am happy to resolve this. Basically, elastic search engine was not running. After resolving this problem, I seem to have hit another problem.

This is how we search using elastic search(below). Right?

```
@articles = Article.search(params[:q]).records
```

When I search with certain parameters, I could see that @articles is of below written object type.

```
#<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Records:0xa227324>
```

Now, when I iterate over the @articles, I can not. I get:

```
[404] {"error":"IndexMissingException[[articles] missing]","status":404}
```

Any thoughts would be appreciable.

I would be happy to share more details if anybody want to know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about the response if you run this http request on your terminal? `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/articles/_mapping?pretty"`

Comment: Hi @HosangJeon, It is:

{
  "error" : "IndexMissingException[[articles] missing]",
  "status" : 404
}

Comment: @HosangJeon. If I run "curl -XGET "http://localhost:3000/articles/_mapping?pretty", I get response. My rails server is running at port number 3000.

Comment: I think you have no Index for 'articles' as the error response said.